# The Great Binary Puzzle - Part 1

Tags: cipher

You are in a dark room with 1 source of light (a lamp). You see a large door with a combination with nothing but letters. You find a sheet of paper stuck in the door with the numbers,

"010101000110100001100101 0110011101110010011001010110000101110100 011000100110100101101110011000010111001001111001 01101100011011110110001101101011 0110100101110011 011011110110111001100101 01110011011101000110010101110000 01100001011101110110000101111001 0111010001101111 01110110011010010110001101110100011011110111001001111001 00101110"

What does this mean?

---

SPOILER!!!!!!......

> *This is ASCII binary text. Will be making another one in a little.*

Comment: This shouldn't be as easy as just copy and paste. http://www.binaryhexconverter.com/binary-to-ascii-text-converter

Comment: Maybe I'll make the next one harder....

Comment: Based on the decoded message, does that mean the actual door combination is that entire string? In the first place who'd have an ASCII table memorized?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Depending on what encoding you use and what endianness you use, it can mean lots of things. Assuming Big Endian UTF8/ASCII it gives "The great binary lock is one step away to victory." (thank you Brainfuck). Nothing else to go on with.

Comment: CORRECT (and it's ASCII)!

Answer (score -2):

I decoded this binary text to real letter text using [this](http://www.roubaixinteractive.com/PlayGround/Binary_Conversion/Binary_To_Text.asp) web-site and the result was the following: Thegreatbinarylockisonestepawaytovictory