# The Great Binary Puzzle - Part 2

Tags: cipher

You pass the first room to enter the second room. It isn't that dim like the first room so it is easier to see. You see another combination, but this time you see something scraped on the wall that's different from the last code. It says "54686572652069732061206c69676874206e6561722c2062757420746865206c696768742069736e5c2774207468652077617920746f207468652070757a7a6c652e2049745c2773206a7573742061207374657020636c6f7365722e". Right under it says "Six and a math term." What does this mean?

Previous parts:
[Part 1](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/4121/the-great-binary-puzzle-part-1)

Comment: This isn't binary...

Comment: I did say it was going to get harder. The puzzle is not just about binary you know...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Six and a math term" just means hexadecimal, which is actually base 16 (not binary).

Hex to ascii translation results in:

> There is a light near, but the light isn\'t the way to the puzzle. It\'s just a step closer.

Comment: Right but the converter added /'s to it.

Answer (score 0):

Take the code and paste it [here](http://www.rapidtables.com/convert/number/hex-to-ascii.htm). 
You will get:

> There is a light near, but the light isn\'t the way to the puzzle. It\'s just a step closer.

This is not binary, but rather, hexadecimal.

Answer (score 0):

Hex to ascii translation:

> There is a light near, but the light isn\'t the way to the puzzle. It\'s just a step closer.