# The Great Binary Puzzle - Part 3

Tags: cipher

There are 2 rooms left and it's lighter than the other 2. You enter the 3rd room. You see a door with a key lock and you see a cartridge and a TV with a Nintendo Entertainment System. You look at the cartridge and it says play me. You put the cartridge in the NES and you get this message: "So you have finished 2 rooms, there is still 1 room left after this one. Press start to get your next message." You take the NES controller and press start. You see a message that says:

> 131 157 165 040 150 141 166 145 040 155 141 144 145 040 151 164 040 164 150 151 163 040 146 141 162 056 040 147 157 157 144 040 152 157 142 056 040 124 150 145 040 153 145 171 040 151 163 040 042 111 156 040 164 150 145 040 154 151 147 150 164 054 040 142 165 164 040 157 165 164 163 151 144 145 040 164 150 145 040 154 151 147 150 164 056 042, 55 73 65 20 79 6f 75 72 20 6b 6e 6f 77 6c 65 64 67 65 2e, 01010100 01101000 01100101 00100000 01101110 01100101 01111000 01110100 00100000 01110000 01100001 01110010 01110100 00100000 01110111 01101111 01101110 01110100 00100000 01100010 01100101 00100000 01110011 01101111 00100000 01100101 01100001 01110011 01111001 00101110

Where is the key and what does this message mean?

Previous parts:
[Part 1](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/4121/the-great-binary-puzzle-part-1)
[Part 2](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/4126/the-great-binary-puzzle-part-2)

Comment: You forgot the code behind hexadecimal and binary. But that's right.

Comment: Got it! Good puzzle.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The first section is

> Octal, it translates to: You have made it this far, good job. The key is "In the light, but outside the light."

---

The second section is

> hex, it translates to: Use your knowledge,

---

The last section is

> binary, it translates to: the next part won't be so easy.

---

Altogether that's

> You have made it this far, good job. The key is "In the light, but outside the light." Use your knowledge, the next part won't be so easy.

Comment: CORRECT!!! But did you find the key.....

Comment: @kp I don't know? The letter e?

Comment: ..... I'll tell you. The key is inside the lamp, but not inside the light source. Technically, It's inside the glass, but not the light itself.

Comment: I'll forever remember the answer. It put me over the 2000 rep mark. I got moderator tools privledges!

Comment: WOW!! GOOD FOR YOU!! I'm still at 121.

Comment: Looks back and sees I've grown by 3000 rep since. To celebrate I edited the answer lol