# The Great Binary Puzzle - Part 4

Tags: logical-deduction

You have made it to the last room. It is very bright, but suddenly you realize that all the codes you've been reading have been different machine codes.

You see the final note scripted on the large door with 4 light bulbs with a different light power. It says:

> This is the last room in this great puzzle. You're prize will be to
>   live forever. There are no codes here, but solve this, Here you have
>   the 4 changeable light bulbs. Put them in order, remember all of the
>   rooms.

How do you solve this puzzle?

Previous parts:
[Part 1](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/4121/the-great-binary-puzzle-part-1)
[Part 2](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/4126/the-great-binary-puzzle-part-2)
[Part 3](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/4711/the-great-binary-puzzle-part-3)

Comment: Ideally a puzzle should stand alone, or, if it depends on other puzzles, should have a link to those.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Put them from dimmest to brightest. Referring back to the earlier puzzles, each one gets progressively brighter than the last.

Comment: CORRECT!!!! YOU WIN ETERNAL LIFE!!!